# Wildcards in Standard ML

Tags: wildcard, sml, ml

I just came across the following function in *ML for the Working Programmer*:

```
fun null [] = true
    | null (_::_) = false
```

1) Can't both wildcards be empty lists?  If not, how does ML prevent this?

2) Could the function be shortened to be:

```
fun null [] = true 
    | false
```

Why / why not?

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, they can, but the matched list won't be empty, so the result of the `null` function holds, i.e., `[] :: []`, which is equivalent to `[[]]`, is not an empty list.
2. No, that's syntactically invalid. However, it can be shortened to this:

```ml
fun null [] = true 
  | null _ = false
```

Comment: Small correction: The input where both wildcards match the empty list would be `[[]]`. With `[[], []]` only the first wildcard matches the empty list - the second matches `[[]]`.

Comment: @sepp2k thanks! You are, indeed, right. I've adjusted my answer accordingly.